# User Registration with error: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to use Django's default Auth to handle register and log in.

`setting.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'books.User'
```

`books.models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {'form': form,})
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/login/$', login),
    (r'^accounts/logout/$', logout),
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', profile),
    (r'^accounts/register/$', register),
)
```

I tried deleting the `db.sqlite3` file and re-ran `python manage.py syncdb` but I still get this error message:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/register/
no such table: auth_user
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.7b4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: auth_user
```

Comment: Do you get any error during syncdb?

Comment: no, it works well:
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin, contenttypes, books, auth, sessions
  Apply all migrations: (none)
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Update

You are probably getting this error because you are using `UserCreationForm` modelform, in which in `META` it contains `User`(django.contrib.auth.models > User) as model.

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
```

And here you are using your own custom auth model, so tables related to `User` has not been created. So here you have to use your own custom modelform. where in Meta class, model should be your `User`(books.User) model

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if it solves your issue. @user2988464

Comment: Wanna ask an elementary question, how can I see the source file of UserCreationForm?

Comment: here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py @user2988464

Answer (score 113):

```
./manage.py migrate
```

If you've just enabled all the middlewares etc this will run each migration and add the missing tables.

Comment: This is the answer that should work for anyone running into this issue, I was about to write a post in this thread but it has been answered here. I also ran **py manage.py makemigrations** then **py manage.py migrate** and everything was fixed, I doubt **manage.py makemigrations** was needed though

Comment: this won't run everywhere like pythonanywhere where we don't have sudo access

Answer (score 50):

Only thing you need to do is :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and after that:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

after that you can select username and password.

here is the sample output:

```
Username (leave blank to use 'hp'): admin
Email address: xyz@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
```

Comment: this answer work for me good but how can run it in docker for the first time installed

Answer (score 12):

This will work for django version <1.7:

Initialize the tables with the command

```
manage.py syncdb
```

This allows you to nominate a "super user" as well as initializing any tables.

Answer (score 10):

it is need to make migration before create superuser.

```py
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

```py
python manage.py createsuperuser
Username : admin
Password : 12345678
```

`python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 7):

Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
try running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

then run

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 6):

For custom forms( if you have made your own forms) use this command to migrate

> python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! I was literally searching for it like for half an hour!

Answer (score 4):

If using a custom auth model, in your UserCreationForm subclass, you'll have to override both the metaclass and clean_username method as it references a hardcoded User class (the latter just until django 1.8).

```
class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        try:
            self.Meta.model.objects.get(username=username)
        except self.Meta.model.DoesNotExist:
            return username

        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
            code='duplicate_username',
        )
```

Comment: I tried this, and I get '''IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level'''

Answer (score 3):

Before creating a custom user model, a first migration must be performed. Then install the application of your user model and add the AUTH_USER_MODEL.

As well:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

On Django 1.11 I had to do this after following instructions in docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

```sh
# create default database:
./manage.py migrate

# create my custom model migration:
# running `./manage.py makemigrations` was not enough
./manage.py makemigrations books
# specify one-off defaults

# create table with users:
./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what I did wrong but got to the point where I decided to clear the whole database. So I ran the command:

```
python manage.py flush
```

After that my database was clear then I ran the commands;

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

then:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following flow

```
$ django-admin createproject <your project name>
```

under `<your project dict>` type `django-admin createapp <app name>`

under `<app name>/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)
```

Go to the root project. Then `$python manage.py migrate`

Then it asks for username and password

Answer (score 1):

Just perform migrations before registering the user.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 6 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, please consider refraining from answering.

Answer (score 1):

theres four steps for adding a custom user model to django

1. Create a CustomUser model
2. update project/settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL
3. customize UserCreationForm & UserChangeForm
4. add the custom user model to admin.py

you missed customize forms , add the CustomUser and CustomUserAdmin to admin.site.register() , then makemigrations nd migrate .

```
#proj_app/forms.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
            model = get_user_model()
            fields = ('email','username',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
            model = get_user_model()
            fields = ('email',  'username',)

#proj_app/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm , CustomUserChangeForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email','username',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

here we extend the existing UserAdmin into CustomUserAdmin and tell django to use our new forms, custom user model, and list only the email and username of a user also we could add more of existing User fields to list_display

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem "no such table: auth_user" when I was trying to deploy one of my Django website in a virtual environment.

Here is my solution which worked in my case:

In your settings.py file where you defined your database setting like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',

        'NAME': os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'db.sqlite3'),
     }
 }
```

just locate your db.sqlite3 database or any other database that you are using and write down a full path of your database , so the database setting will now look something like this ;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/django/django_project/db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I hope that your problem will resolve now.

Answer (score 0):

**python manage.py makemigrations then → python manage.py migrate**  fixes it.

> Assuming Apps defined/installed in settings.py exist in the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how many python instances are running in background like in windows go--->task manager and check python instances and kill or end task i.e kill all python instances. run again using "py manage.py runserver" command.
i hope it will be work fine....

Answer (score 0):

If You did any changes in project/app then execute:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 0):

call these command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```