# OperationalError at /accounts/register/ no such table: auth_user

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, django-forms

I know there are tons of question on this topic but I already try it all and nothing works for me . why it only creating `auth_group` and not `auth_user` ? and how to add the `auth_user` ?

forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from custom_user.models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__( *args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email",)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        exclude = ()
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682155/django-user-registration-with-error-no-such-table-auth-user) SO question.

Comment: i already try but i still get the same error @JeroenHeier