# Django's manage.py createsuperuser gives error OperationalError: 'no such table'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication

I am working on my Final Year Project. I wanted to extend the default User model that Django provides in order to add some more attributes. I added following code in my `models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Also in `settings.py` I added:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'esacp.User'
```

where `esacp` is the name of my app.

After doing all of this, I ran `python manage.py makemigrations esacp`, then I ran `python manage.py migrate` in my Windows Command Prompt. Both of these commands worked perfectly.

Now, I went to create an admin role for my Django Web App, in order to manage the things as a superuser, when I ran the command `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it asked me for the username, after I entered username and pressed 'Enter', it gave me the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: esacp_user

A screenshot of the whole error:

[image]

Where did I make a mistake or miss anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django: User Registration with error: no such table: auth\_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682155/django-user-registration-with-error-no-such-table-auth-user)

Comment: @mkrieger1 it does not answer my question as I have just installed Django and made few Models in models.py, and tried to extend the default User Model provided by Django, and it is not creating superuser when I try to.

Comment: Can you post the migration file that was created after you ran `makemigrations`

Answer (score 1):

I think this error raise after shifting the Default user model to CustomUserModel

#### ----- Follow those steps ------

```
1 - Delete (migrations) folder
2 - Delete (db.sqlite3) databse
3 - Run command (python manage.py makemigrations your_appname)
4 - Run command (python manage.py migrate)
5 - Run command (python manage.py createsuperuser)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article for the best help!! It worked for me.[Real Python](https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/#:%7E:text=The%20Django%20admin%20is%20a,do%20almost%20anything%20you%20want.)

After Creating your Django project, change your directory -

```
cd (your PROJECT NAME)
```

And then run the following commands-

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
Username:
Email:
Password :
Password(again) :
```