# Can't create Django superuser

Tags: django, git

I have an empty Django project (with two empty apps set in settings.py). The project is cloned from github. I need to work on it locally. It worked fine, until I tried to change username to email in user registration form. I did some modifications (don't remember which exactly, as I am stuck on this problem probably for a week or more). When I try to create superuser, i get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 100, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 140, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/laptop/WorkProjects/Mindsum/Apps/mindsum_be/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

I've seen people with the same problem in the internet, but it wasn't helpful for me.. Could anyone help me please to solve this error? The projects worked really fine, and I was able to create superuser, but after some changes (which were done on my branch) related to user registration, it stopped working. I changed my branch to "develop" branch, and from there created a new branch, with hope that with new branch I will be able to begin everything from the beginning. But the problem wasn't gone....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django: User Registration with error: no such table: auth\_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682155/django-user-registration-with-error-no-such-table-auth-user)

Comment: use command. `python manage.py migrate` then `python manage.py createsuperuser`