# Django project only works locally, not on Heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, deployment

When I run my django project on my local pc, it works perfectly fine and I can sign up/log in/log out on my site. When I deploy it to Heroku, it doesn't work anymore, giving me the following error:

> OperationalError at /login/
>
> no such table: auth_user

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682155/user-registration-with-error-no-such-table-auth-user) question exists, and I've already tried all the solutions, but it still hasn't worked. **I've done migrate and makemigrations** on both the python and heroku side, along with the commit command at different intervals. I also don't even have the usercreateform, and OP's error for that question appeared on their local pc, not just Heroku. I also tried creating a super user, which I could on my local pc, but not on Heroku.

If it helps, my procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

I had a hard time determining my procfile, so maybe that's the problem? The django_project part is just the name of the folder that includes settings.py and wsgi.py.

Forms.py:

```
class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']

class NewMessageForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['content','reciever']
```

If you want to see my site in action, go to newsment.herokuapp.com and try to sign up or login (it will give the error).

Comment: please run migration on heroku

Comment: Run ```python manage.py migrate``` on Heroku

Comment: Maybe django thinks the migrations with auth_user table are already applied? if your'e using mysql I recommend you to delete your database before attempting to migrate.... for sqlite, deleting your db.sqlite file will do. (that's if you're starting and don't have important data to lose)

Comment: @ram I already did

Comment: @KiranChauhan I already did

Comment: @JulioGonzález Thank you for your response! I deleted the db.sqlite file, ran migrations and makemigrations again, pushed the changes to heroku... but it still gave me the same error:(

Comment: You can't use SQLite with Heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem. Please see the linked duplicates.

Comment: @Chris ah, thank you, I'll try that. Do you know why this one doesn't work while this one https://github.com/redianmarku/Django-Twitter-Clone works? They both use sqlite, and it was the program I based mine off of (but after I changed it, it doesn't work anymore)

Comment: @Chris also is there an alternative to Heroku that does accept sqlite? that's also dynamic (not netlify)

Comment: @Chris also how is this https://learning-log.herokuapp.com/ (from Al Sweigart's book) possible if heroku doesn't accept sqlite? So basically, why me?

Comment: That hosted "learning-log" site tells us nothing about how it is built. It's irrelevant. And the Twitter clone uses a MySQL driver, so it probably uses MySQL. We're not here to read thousands of lines of code and explain how they work. Please take _five minutes_ and search "heroku sqlite" on your favourite search engine. There are countless resources explaining this, and it is your responsibility to [do a bit of work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/354577). Don't ask "why me?" and feel sorry for yourself. _Learn_.

Comment: @Chris ...sorry, I promise this is the last question: Why does the Twitter clone have: "web: gunicorn Django-Twitter-Clone.wsgi --log-file -"? There's clearly not a folder marked 'django-twitter-clone', so how does it possibly work? Shouldn't it be 'django_project.wsgi" instead? Thanks

Comment: That's a random person's random codebase shared on the Internet. I have no reason to believe it's correct, and I'm not going to dig into it to figure out how it works (or doesn't). Yes, it should probably be `django_project.wsgi`, but that's a question _for the author of that codebase_, not us. Submit an issue and ask them.

Comment: @Chris ah, thanks, I just thought you knew why.

Comment: Are you using multiple accounts ([Rebecca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16203021/rebecca) and [Rebecca Bibye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13985847/rebecca-bibye))? That's not strictly against the rules, but [it is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35593/248627). It's disconcerting to talk to multiple accounts belonging to the same person in one thread.

Comment: @Chris haha I read your link and it said it's fine as long as I'm not voting for my other account (which I'm not, obviously)